# json error JSON.parse: unexpected end of data error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The following string is returned as response from a web request:

> [[1367366400000,6435.00],[1370044800000,349004.49],[1372636800000,1178831.00],
>   [1375315200000,2906943.00],[1377993600000,3571615.00],[1380585600000,3852076.00],
>   [1383264000000,3656850.00],[1385856000000,306884.00]]

now when I try to

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

It is giving me an error:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected end of data error
```

I also tried:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
```

It does not give any error, but it also does not convert the text to JSON object.

Comment: The given response from your web request already evaluates as valid javascript. You could pass it to a variable directly, but you need to evaluate it. var data=eval('[[13...');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because the response is not JSON at all, it's a simple array and use `eval()` to parse it in a new variable.

```
var myVar=null;
eval('myVar=' + response );
if(myVar)
    console.log(myVar);
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this and why - it is generally valid. Using `eval()` may not be considered good practice but its still a valid choice?

Comment: I don'r care of downvote, yes ! you could check for count of `[` and compare theme to count of `]` if if first character is: (`[`) and last character is: (`]`) and every brace has a match one for closing brace, that's a good choice